# Is there anyway I can play a video on login

Tags: 10.10, login

I have this video clip that I want ubuntu to play when I login, is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 7):

Add the command `totem --fullscreen /path/to/video` to your startup applications (or replace totem with your video player of choice).

Comment: You can add `--fullscreen` to the command in order to have the video play in full screen